# Difference of Green's function for heat equation between Neumann and Dirichlet B.C.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, greens-function

I was asked to implement, using the appropriate Green's function, the solution to the 2D heat equation on a rectangle:

$I_t=I_{xx}+I_{yy}$

with Neumann B.C. : $\overrightarrow{n}\cdot(\overrightarrow{\nabla}I)$

where  $\overrightarrow{n}$ is the normal to the domain and  $\overrightarrow{\nabla}I$ is the gradient of $I$

according to [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function), the Green's function for this problem is given by $H(t)\frac{1}{4\pi t}e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{4t}}$
where $H(t)$ is the heaviside function.

Is this Green's function applies for both Neumann and Dirichlet B.Cs?

if so, how do I take Neumann B.C. into consideration when solving for $I$.